# I have to compare if student has more than 51 with FOR

Tags: python

So I have this list

```
Journal = {"vasadze" : 78 , "shonia": 86 ,"mosiava": 45, "kalandadze":36 , "sirbiladze":64 }
```

and I have to know which students passed exam (51 score) and which didn't, and put them in dictionary

```
passed_ones = {}
not_passed_ones = {}
```

I did it, but what bothers me is that my teacher has this hint:

```
for the_key, the_value in Journal.items():
   print (the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value
```

I did it like this:

```
if Journal["vasadze] >= 51:
    passed_ones["vasadze"] = 78
else:
    not_passed_ones["vasadze"] = 78
```

I guess he wants me to do with for(?) but I don't know how

Comment: The Pyhton language is so "human readable" that you just have to do this: for each student in the students list, if the student result is greater or equal to 51 put it in the passed_ones list, otherwise put it in the not_passed_ones list.     I used the word "list" but Journal and passed_ones/not_passed_ones are Python dictionaries (key/value items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is only going to move a single item to one of those new dictionaries. Your teacher is telling you to do it for the entire first dictionary and they are giving you the method to do that you just have to apply it.

```py
for the_key, the_value in Journal.items():      # this will give you the keys and values
   print(the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value)  # this will print them out
```

You need to do your method but insert them into the other dictionaries combining the two things:

```py
for the_key, the_value in Journal.items():
    if the_value >= 51:                          # you can reference this directly
        passed_ones[the_key] = the_value         # reference key directly as well to insert it into the new dictionary equal to the value
    else:
        not_passed_ones[the_key] = the_value     # same as before
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hard coding the names, the names are the dict keys you should use this as the key in the passed/not passed dicts.

```
for the_key, the_value in Journal.items():
   if the_value >= 51:
      passed_ones[the_key] = the_value
   else:
      not_passed_ones[the_key] = the_value
```